# Loading layout as 'this' in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

It looks like a kind of wrong approach, but I'd still ask.

The task is, you have a layout xml that describes a composite widget (like `Button` + `TextView`). You'd like to make it re-usable, so you build a class like `MyTextViewButtonWidget` - it will expose its button text accessors and it will also do the same for text view:

```
public class MyTextViewButtonWidget extends LinearLayout {
    ...
    void setButtonText(String text) { ... }
    String getButtonText() { ... }
    void setTextViewText(String text) { ... }
    String getTextViewText() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Layout definition looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout ..........>
   ....button and text label here...
</LinearLayout>
```

The question is - how would you load this layout so that its root `LinearLayout` would be the `LinearLayout` part of `MyTextViewButtonWidget`?

Tried defining `MyTextViewButtonWidget`'s ctor like this:

```
{
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.reusable_widget_layout, this);
}
```

But this loads `reusable_widget_layout` as a child to `MyTextViewButtonWidget` (that's not what I need).

Generally, the problem is:

- You need to create a composite widget
- You'd like to be able to define its layout with xml markup
- You'd like it to load root's child widgets defined in xml as its child widgets (INSTEAD OF: load the whole hierarchy from xml as a single child of your reusable widget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
<LinearLayout ..........>
   ....button and text label here...
</LinearLayout>
```

with:

```
<merge ..........>
   ....button and text label here...
</merge>
```